# Getting $.proxy to work inside $.each with .val()

Tags: javascript, jquery, proxy

I am trying to send each .val() value to a proxy function with jQuery, but it is not working.

The code I am using is the following:

```
$('input').each( $.proxy( function(index, domEl){
    this.doMyFunctionWith( domEl.val() );
}, this));
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint there and seeing what the value of `this` is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use:

```
$(domEl).val()
```

since `domEl` is (unsurprisingly) a DOM element, and not a jQuery object.

Answer (score -1):

In what context are you writing this code? perhaps you need to do var that = this and then pass that to the proxy as the second parameter.

Comment: No i think the context is good, when I do `console.log(domEl.val())` before the function, I get `undefined`.